# can I specify IP soure or interface in packet sender

Tags: ip, flooding

I use packet sender to generate UDP flooding traffic. However, I have multiple NICs and the NIC packet sender using is not what I want. How do I specify the NIC in the packet sender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Latest release of Packet Sender now supports this.

The UDP traffic generator does not bind to custom IPs in the current release. It only does a general bind. That has been added for the next release.

Actual commit with the fix:
https://github.com/dannagle/PacketSender/commit/0c0e60d33a6e4a378c0395e347bc95d2a955d22a

Hopefully, new people visiting this question will have it available.

Until that fix gets released, you can use the CLI version of the UDP traffic tool with this bindip option:

```
-B, --bindip <IP>         Bind custom IP. Default is IP:Any.
```